# TFS 2017 missing "Path Filter" for specifying CI trigger?

Tags: .net, git, tfs, tfs-2017

We've recently moved our code to Git and when attempting to update some of our CI builds for specific projects, I noticed that I only have the option to filter on branch, not path.

Specifically, the repository is a .NET solution with multiple projects. I want to specify a single project to build if changes are made to that path (for the stage branch in this case), but there's no option to do so. Currently, this definition (of which there are dozens) are all running because I cannot filter by a specific project in the solution.

Is this possible? I see other versions of TFS seem to have it, but I do not see it in ours. Thank you.

EDIT: I should note I'm using a remote Git repository for the definitions, not the built-in Git repository provided by TFS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to upgrade your TFS 2017 to the latest edition (TFS 2017 Update 3.1). I've checked my Tfs2017.Update3 (15.117.27414.0), `Path Filter` option does exists.

[image]

Comment: I am using that version it seems. I should note I'm NOT using the built-in Git repository, but rather a remote repository stored on Github.

Comment: If this is the case, you could import your reop from Github to DevOps, or using Azure DevOps Service instead of Azure DevOps Server.

Comment: Moving from Github to DevOps is absolutely not what we wish to do.

Comment: Then migrate from Azure DevOps server to Azure DevOps service (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/) might be an option.